# Primitive Root Modulo $m$

Tags: primitive-roots

I need help with the following: Show that if $b$ is a primitive root modulo $m$, then $$\{b,b^2,b^3,...,b^m-1\}$$ is a complete set of units modulo $m$.

Comment: How is $p$ related to $m$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I fixed it.

Comment: What is your definition of primitive root?

Comment: I think you want $m$ to be prime.

Comment: If $m$ is not prime, then although your set indeed lists all members of the multiplicative group, there are some repetitions.

Comment: Yes, m would be a prime. A primitive would be an integer b s.t. {0,b,b^2,...,b^m-1}  a complete set of representatives for Z/mZ. I believe I'm meant to write a proof for the primitive root theorem.

Comment: Primitive roots exist for precisely $1,2,4$ and powers of odd primes. But they are of serious interest mainly for primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we define a primitive root as an element with order $\varphi(m)$ modulo $m$, then we can prove as follows. Each power $b^i$ is coprime to $m$, and there are $\varphi(m)$ integers coprime to $m$. Now, if $b^i\equiv b^j\pmod{m}$, then $b^{i-j}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$, so $\varphi(m)|i-j$. It follows that each of the powers are distinct modulo $m$, and thus each integer relatively prime to $m$ is some power $b^i$ modulo $m$.